# layout clickable selector doesn't work - why?

Tags: android, layout, selector, clickable

Create a login page. but I don't know what problem this code
login button don't work change color when I clicked!

I want to when I click then change color button

why doesn't changed that 'LOGIN' button?

how I can solve this?

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_login"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:paddingRight="32dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_user" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> selector xml -> 
>   **btn_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#4DAEEA" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00ff00" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#999" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make LinearLayout behave like a button by adding style and removing background , follow these steps

```
<LinearLayout
......
style="@style/btn_stand"
.......
>

</LinearLayout>
```

My style definition for the button:

```
<style name="btn_stand" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_stand_sel</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/btn_stand_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
</style>
```

My @drawable/btn_stan_sel file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- disabled state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_stand_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>

    <!-- enabled and pressed state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_stand_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <!-- enabled and focused state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_stand_focused" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>

    <!-- enabled state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_stand_enabled" android:state_enabled="true"/>

</selector>
```

My drawable file repeated for each state just with different colors for each state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/stroke" />

    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />

    <corners android:radius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

this was an example that works for me , hope you use it and choose the color you want

Comment: Thanks! but, real problem is item order first come in 'android:state_enabled' should be come first 'android:state_pressed'

Comment: I don't think it's a probleme , but did u solve your problem ?

Comment: Yeah solved. Can't I use "state_enabled" first? if i use 'state_pressed'

Comment: I think the standing doesn't create a problem

Answer (score -1):

Add  `android:focusable="true"`to your linear layout xml code.

In the event that that doesn't work, you can try to replace `android:background=@drawable/btn_login` with `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`.